# Asynchronously calling a callback function in Spidermonkey JS engine

Tags: javascript, c++, spidermonkey

Using Spidermonkey v27:

What is the proper way to "retain" and then asynchronously call a temporary JS function from C++?

JS code:

```
myFunction(function(){
    console.log("The function works");
});
```

C++ code:

```
bool js_myFunction(JSContext* cx, uint32_t argc, jsval* vp)
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        implement_async_function(cx, vp);
        JS_SET_RVAL(cx, vp, JSVAL_NULL);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static JSContext* savedContext;
static jsval* savedVal;
void implement_async_function(JSContext* cx, jsval* vp)
{
    // if the function is called immediately, everything is okay!
    jsval retVal;
    JS_CallFunctionValue(cx, nullptr, *vp, 0, nullptr, &retVal);
    // "The function works"

    // if some work has to be done before calling the callback...
    savedContext = cx;
    savedVal = vp;
    start_async_process();
}

void async_process_complete()
{
    jsval retVal;
    JS_CallFunctionValue(savedContext, nullptr, *savedVal, 0, nullptr, &retVal);
    // "<no filename="filename">:0:true is not a function"
    // or else it crashes...
}

void alternate_implement_async_function(JSContext* cx, jsval* vp)
{
    // also tried this:
    savedContext = cx;
    savedVal = vp;
    JS_AddValueRoot(savedContext, savedVal);
    start_async_process();

    // and this:
    savedContext = cx;
    savedVal = new jsval(*vp);
    JS_AddValueRoot(savedContext, savedVal);
    start_async_process();

    // and using JS::RootedValue

    // and using JS::Heap<JS::Value>

    // and using the global context instead of the saved context
}
```

I've read through SpiderMonkey's documents:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS::Value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/GC_Rooting_Guide

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS_AddRoot

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_CallFunctionValue

And checked this StackOverflow post [Spidermonkey and Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599589/spidermonkey-and-garbage-collection)

And tried even making the JS callback function a global function which should never be garbage collected. (This is not what I want though.)

Comment: Have you considered joining the *mozilla irc*? https://wiki.mozilla.org/IRC I suspect that someone there will be able to help you instantly.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the behavior of your program when trying to call the function asynchronously, but I assume that it would seg fault when trying to call the function since the GC might have moved it. You need a way to store the function *object* (it's not a value as in your code). `JS::Rooted` is not acceptable in this situation since stack rooting expects gc things to root in a LIFO ordering. Thus, you need to store it in a `JS::Heap<JSObject*>` handle. The `JS::Heap` handle expects to live on the heap instead of the stack (maybe in a list or tree structure). The caveat with `JS::Heap` handles is that they need to be traced by the GC so the underlying objects can be relocated and your handle updated. Tracing is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393732/how-to-create-handle-and-destroy-jsheapt-objects-in-spidermonkey/27960128#27960128).

Assuming your object is now stored properly and traced, you should be able to call it at any time without any issue.