# How to create, handle, and destroy JS::Heap<T> objects in Spidermonkey?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, spidermonkey

Using **Spidermonkey 24, 38, 45**

[Spidermonkey documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/GC_Rooting_Guide) says: "GC thing pointers on the heap must be wrapped in a JS::Heap. The only exception to this is if they are added as roots with the JS_AddRoot() functions or JS::PersistentRooted class, but **don't do this unless** it's really necessary. **JS::Heap pointers must also continue to be traced in the normal way**, which is not covered here."

What exactly does tracing mean in this case? Is the following code missing something?

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(JS::HandleObject bar) : _bar(bar) {}  // Does that root bar?
   ~Foo() {_bar = nullptr;}                  // Does that release memory?

   JS::Heap<JSObject*>  _bar;
};

Foo *create(JSContext *jscontext, JSObject *parent)
{
   JS::RootedObject bar(jscontext, JS_NewObject(jscontext, &SOME_CLASS, NULL, parent));
   return new Foo(bar);
}
```

Do I need to add "tracing"? Do I need to root bar object when it is stored inside Foo? Should I rather use JS_AddRoot() functions to root bar instead of using Heap?

Answer (score 3):

`JS::Heap<T>` are used in data structures which reside on the heap. Tracing is indeed a requirement. Without it, the GC may either determine your object is unreachable or relocate it without updating your `JS::Heap<T>` handle.

Tracing objects in spidermonkey is simple. You need to request an extra GC root tracer using `JS_AddExtraGCRootsTracer(JSRuntime* rt, JSTraceDataOp traceOp, void* data)`. The JSTraceDataOp is a function pointer with the interface `void traceOp(JSTracer* trc, void* data)`. In your function, you must call the various `JS_Call<T>Tracer` (defined in *Tracer.h*) methods passing the tracer and your object. Additionally, you should call `JS_TraceChildren` as necessary.

Using your example, adding a tracer might look something like the following.

```
Foo* ref = create(cx, nullptr);

void trace_foos(JSTracer* tracer, void* data) {
   JS_CallHeapObjectTracer(tracer, &(ref->_bar), "foo");
}

JS_AddExtraGCRootsTracer(rt, trace_foos, nullptr);
```

Whenever GC runs, your trace callback will run and you should traverse your object graph and trace GC things as you go.

As for the questions in your comments -

```
   Foo(JS::HandleObject bar) : _bar(bar) {}  // Does that root bar?
```

`bar` is already rooted on the stack by the `JS::RootedObject` bar in `Foo* create`. `Heap<T>` handles are not roots - this is why they must be traced. As soon as `create` returns, the object is no longer rooted.

```
  ~Foo() {_bar = nullptr;}                  // Does that release memory?
```

No. `_bar` is just an instance of the `JS::Heap<T>` handle. The thing it points to will be garbage collected on a subsequent cycle.

Comment: Note: I believe `JS::TraceEdge` should be used in latest version of SM instead of now deprecated `JS_CallObjectTracer`. (And `JSContext *` instead of `JSRuntime *`)

Answer (score 1):

Based on jwilm's answer here is an example of a Foo class implementation.

```
void trace_obj(JSTracer* tracer, void* data)
{
    JS_CallObjectTracer(tracer, (JS::Heap<JSObject*>*)data, "jsobj");
}

class Foo                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                     
public:                                                                                                                                                                               
   Foo(JSRuntime *rt, JS::HandleObject bar)                                                                                                                                           
     : _rt(rt),                                                                                                                                                                        
     _bar(bar)                                                                                                                                                                      
   {                                                                                                                                                                                  
     if (_bar.get())                                                                                                                                                                  
       JS_AddExtraGCRootsTracer(_rt, trace_obj, &_bar);                                                                                                                               
   }                                                                                                                                                                                  
   Foo(Foo const &f)                                                                                                                                           
     : _rt(f._rt),                                                                                                                                                                        
     _bar(f._bar)                                                                                                                                                                      
   {                                                                                                                                                                                  
     if (_bar.get())                                                                                                                                                                  
       JS_AddExtraGCRootsTracer(_rt, trace_obj, &_bar);                                                                                                                               
   }                                                                                                                                                                                  
   ~Foo()                                                                                                                                                                             
   {                                                                                                                                                                                  
     if (_bar.get())                                                                                                    
       JS_RemoveExtraGCRootsTracer(_rt, trace_obj, &_bar);                                                                                 
   }                                                                                                                                                                                  

private:                                                                                                                
   JSRuntime *_rt;                                                                                                                                                                    
   JS::Heap<JSObject*> _bar;                                                                                                                                                          
};
```

Comment: Note: I believe `JS::TraceEdge` should be used in latest version of SM instead of now deprecated `JS_CallObjectTracer`. (And `JSContext *` instead of `JSRuntime *`)