# Storing the global js object in JS::Heap<T> provokes crash in JS_DestroyRuntime if still in scope

Tags: memory-management, spidermonkey

After learning from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393732/how-to-create-handle-and-destroy-jsheapt-objects-in-spidermonkey), 
I'm trying to store SpiderMonkey's global object on the heap. This seems to work as long as it goes out of scope before `JS_DestroyRuntime` is called. In my code however, the global object is a class member and thus cannot go out of scope before the runtime is destroyed in the class's destructor.

Unfortunately, this leads to the Monkey crashing in `JS::~Heap` with the following stack trace:

```
1  js::gc::Cell::storeBuffer() const                                                    Heap.h       1339 0x10004f905 
2  JSObject::writeBarrierPost(void *, JSObject *, JSObject *)                           jsobj.h      655  0x1000a6fc8 
3  js::InternalGCMethods<JSObject *>::postBarrier(JSObject * *, JSObject *, JSObject *) Barrier.h    254  0x1000a6df0 
4  JS::HeapObjectPostBarrier(JSObject * *, JSObject *, JSObject *)                      Barrier.cpp  173  0x100bc1636 
5  js::GCMethods<JSObject *>::postBarrier(JSObject * *, JSObject *, JSObject *)         RootingAPI.h 551  0x100003065 
6  JS::Heap<JSObject *>::post(JSObject * const&, JSObject * const&)                     RootingAPI.h 271  0x10000302b 
7  JS::Heap<JSObject *>::~Heap()                                                        RootingAPI.h 237  0x10000369e 
8  JS::Heap<JSObject *>::~Heap()                                                        RootingAPI.h 236  0x100002f75 
9  MyMonkeyClass::~MyMonkeyClass()                                                      main.cpp     64   0x100003725 
10 MyMonkeyClass::~MyMonkeyClass()                                                      main.cpp     58   0x100002aa5 
11 main                                                                                 main.cpp     110  0x100002a12 
12 start                                                                                                  0x1000029d4
```

Here is a minimal example triggering the problem. I've left the GC tracing calls out intentionally, they don't change the outcome.

```
#include <js/Initialization.h>
#include <jsapi.h>
#include <QDebug>

// The class of the global object. Just a dummy.
static JSClass global_class = {
    "global",
    JSCLASS_GLOBAL_FLAGS,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    JS_GlobalObjectTraceHook
};

class MyMonkeyClass
{
public:
    MyMonkeyClass() {
        Q_ASSERT( JS_Init() );
        auto runtime = JS_NewRuntime( 5 * 1024 * 1024 /*heap space*/ );
        Q_ASSERT( runtime );
        m_context = JS_NewContext( runtime, 8192 /*default. keep.*/ );
        Q_ASSERT( m_context );

        JSAutoRequest ar( m_context );

        // Not sure which of these alternatives is the correct way with JS::Heap
        m_global = JS::RootedObject( m_context,
                                   JS_NewGlobalObject( m_context, &global_class, nullptr, JS::FireOnNewGlobalHook ) );
        //global = JS_NewGlobalObject( context, &global_class, nullptr, JS::FireOnNewGlobalHook );
        Q_ASSERT( m_global.get() );
    }

    ~MyMonkeyClass() {
        auto runtime = JS_GetRuntime( m_context );
        JS_DestroyContext( m_context );
        JS_DestroyRuntime( runtime );
        JS_ShutDown();
    }

private:
    JSContext *m_context;
    JS::Heap<JSObject*> m_global;
};

int main( int, char** )
{
    MyMonkeyClass mmc;
    return 0;
}
```

While composing this question I found out that setting `m_global = nullptr;` in the dtor before destroying things actually avoids the crash. Now my final question is:

Is this the correct fix? If yes, why? Does SM maybe assume that a non-null JS::Heap pointer refers to still-in-use memory and thus it panics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your initial problem is caused by a wrong order of object deallocations.**

A C++ class is destructed in a construction reverse order that is, a call to a class destructor is followed by the class member destructors. Members are destroyed in their declaration reverse order. That means that in your case:

1. ~MyMonkeyClass() is entered
2. JS_Destroy* and JS_ShutDown is called
3. JS::~Heap is called. However, JS engine is already gone and that causes undefined behaviour - crash in your case.

By setting m_global to nullptr you prevent JS::~Heap() from going down to JS API to clean up memory. That dodges the crash but leaves you with a possibility of a memory leak.

**A proper fix is cleaning everything up in a correct order.**

One way would be defining a yet another class "JsUpDown" that initialises JS engine, creates JS runtime and JS context in constructor and calls JS_Destroy* and JS_ShutDown in destructor. Then MyMonkeyClass would look like:

```
class MyMonkeyClass
{
  MyMonkeyClass() : m_engine(), m_global() // just to make it explicit
  {
     JSAutoRequest ar(m_engine.m_context);
     m_global = JS::RootedObject(...);
  }
  ~MyMonkeyClass() {} // no need for the destructor now

  JsUpDown m_engine;  // Should be first. The order is important:
                      // Members are destroyed in reverse order.
  JS::Heap<JSObject*> m_global;
};
```